# Mule 4 - flows suddently stopped initializing, warning about some mysterious yml file occurs, MUnit test started throwing unexpected errors

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule4, apikit

I was working on my Mule 4 application today, and suddenly my Anypoint Studio went crazy. When I was trying to run my application, i recieved an error that a port used by the application is already in use. Nothing unusual, but when I have restarted my PC and wanted to run the app again, suspicious information showed up in the console:

> INFO  2021-05-25 12:40:21,056 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct: Flow ImportPendingCorrectionsFlow has not been started
> INFO  2021-05-25 12:40:21,056 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Starting flow: ImportInvoicesFlow
> INFO  2021-05-25 12:40:21,056 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Stopping flow: ImportInvoicesFlow

and the same message for all flows in my application.

Then I tried to run an existing MUnit test, which was running correctly since a month or more, and I recieved this error:

> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>
> - Running test: ImportInvoicesFlowTestWithIncorrectVehicleCount - Test      +
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   java.lang.AssertionError: The error ID thrown does not match the expected one.  expected:<[APP:VALIDATION]> but was:<[HTTP:CONNECTIVITY]>
>   at org.mule.munit.runner.flow.TestFlow.run(TestFlow.java:313)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remotely closed
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remotely closed

This is indeed very strange - as this flow has nothing to do with `HTTP` at all.

Finally, I have discovered a very strange `WARN` in the console:

> WARN  2021-05-25 13:04:35,613 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.agent.configuration.descriptor.YamlMuleAgentDescriptor: Descriptor file /home/xxxxxxx/apps/AnypointStudio-7.7.0-linux64/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.202105101830/mule/conf/invoices-esb-mule4-app.yml not found.

I don't know what's happening here, i have never ever created such a file as `invoices-esb-mule4-app.yml`. I assume that this is some kind of a configuration file created by Mule itself basing on the application name. The path is strange here, as the workspace I'm working on is in `/home/xxxxxxx/AnypointStudio7/workspace-2/`

Other information that can be helpful (or not)

- I was working on an ApiKit SOAP service, but still, it worked fine.
- At one moment, I have misclicked Mule Design perspective and clicked Api Desing perspective, which ended in an application crash, but it SEEMED to be working correctly after starting Anypoint Studio again.

Is anyone having an idea what could have happened to my Anypoint Studio or my application?

Answer (score 6):

I encountered a similar problem in which the logs said `FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Starting flow [flow name]`, then `FlowConstructLifecycleManager: Stopping flow [flow name]`, then `AbstractFlowConstruct: Flow [flow name] has not been started`.  Then repeat those three with the next flow.

After spending more than a day trying various solutions, my team tried going to Run, Run Configurations, select Mule Applications, select the Mule application, General tab, "Clear Application Data:" and changing it to "Always".  It had been "Never".  After making this change and running it again, it started working.  Hope this helps you or someone else with a similar "Stopping flow" problem.

Comment: The solution to clear the application data also solved my issue with the started and immediately stopped flow. After all, it wasn't an issue in the XML but apparently something in the runtime/data.
Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Happy to hear this info helped someone else.  I posted it hoping it would.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The YML could be a per application configuration file created by the Runtime Manager Agent. It is strange that it is create in an execution inside Studio though. Check if the /home/xxxxxxx/apps/AnypointStudio-7.7.0-linux64/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.4.3.0.ee_7.3.5.202105101830/mule/conf/mule-agent.yml is referencing it.